# Add Search Box that Loads Embed YouTube Player

Tags: search, iframe, youtube, embed, playlist

I've looked and tried a BUNCH of different codes and can't figure this out.

What I'd like to do is **add a search box** on my page that **loads a YouTube playlist** based on the **search query** and **plays it on an embedded player**.

**My Code**:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function go_get(){
 var base_url = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=search&list=' ;
 var search_field = document.getElementById('yourtextfield').text ;
 var target_url = base_url + search_field ;
 var ifr = document.getElementById('youriframe') ;
 ifr.src = target_url ;
 return false ;
}

</script> 

<form onsubmit="go_get(); return false;" >
 <input type="text"  id="yourtextfield"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Search Playlists" />
</form>

<iframe id="youriframe" width="640" height="360" ></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

**Result**

The search box and player loads. However, the **same playlist is loaded** no matter what you search.

If I right-click on the video and view the embed HTML this is the result:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6DYngiqZim0?
feature=player_embedded" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

As you can see the src has changed. Could YouTube maybe be preventing this behavior? Perhaps my URL is wrong?

Please Help!

Answer (score 3):

Just change the "text" option with "value" on line 12

```
<html> 
<head>
<title>Youtube playlist search</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function go_get(){
 var base_url = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=search&list=';
 var search_field = document.getElementById('yourtextfield').value;
 var target_url = base_url + search_field;
 var ifr = document.getElementById('youriframe');
 ifr.src = target_url;
 return false;
}

</script> 

<form onsubmit="go_get(); return false;" >
 <input type="text"  id="yourtextfield"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Search Playlists" />
</form>

<iframe id="youriframe" width="640" height="360" ></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
var search_field = document.getElementById('yourtextfield').text ;
```

to:

```
var search_field = document.getElementById('yourtextfield').value ;
```